# Find number of columns unique occurrences for another column using pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a table:

```
id_1        id_2      id_3
47452       IN        13
47452       IN        13
47452       IN        16
31551       GA        6
31551       GA        6
```

How do I find `id_1`'s  that have a number of unique occurrences of (`id_2` and `id_3`) == 1? (using `pandas`)

As a result, here should be returned 31551 only.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'id_1': [47452, 47452, 47452, 31551, 31551], 'id_2': ['IN', 'IN', 'IN', 'GA', 'GA'], 'id_3': [13, 13, 16, 6, 6]}
print(pd.DataFrame(data=d))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can solve this by using groupby on `id_1` then get the number of unique rows of each group based on `id_2` & `id_3`.

Finally we can filter out the groups which have 1 unique row:

```
m = df.groupby('id_1')['id_2','id_3'].transform('nunique').eq(1).all(axis=1)
df[m]
```

**Output**

```
    id_1 id_2  id_3
3  31551   GA     6
4  31551   GA     6
```

---

If you want to get the value of `id_1` back:

```
df[m]['id_1'].unique()
```

**Output**

```
array([31551])
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the solution to your problem can be achieved by using multilevel group by

```
d = {'id_1': [47452, 47452, 47452, 31551, 31551], 'id_2': ['IN', 'IN', 'IN', 'GA', 'GA'], 'id_3': [13, 13, 16, 6, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

result = df.groupby(['id_1','id_2','id_3']).size().groupby(level=0).agg(['size'])

result:
      size
id_1    
31551   1
47452   2
```

you can select the id_1 having only one count by:

```
result[result['size']==1]
      size
id_1    
31551   1
```

Also, you can print list of all id's from result:

```
result[result['size']==1].index.tolist()
output : [31551]
```

Hope this helps.